# Changing Left navigation in MySite (my content) for all users

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, office-365, my-site, quick-launch

In a SharePoint online (office 365) project, I am trying to add two new links to the left navigaion of my-sites, which must be visible for all users. when users go to their My-site (newsfeed). The new links must be visible in the left navigation (quick launch) next to `about me` and `newsfeed`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the links to be added globally for everyone, one way to do it could be by using jQuery and javascript in your MySite master page to add the links. I want to mention that this trick would only work in MySite root level (when users click the "Newsfeed" in the top suite bar) though and not in the Personal Sites because Personal sites are actually their own site collections, but if I understood your question correctly, it shouldn't be a problem because MySite root is where you would actually need the links anyways. :)

As I am not too familiar with the actual scripting, here are some links where you can read up about jQuery and javascript:

1) Check the answer I got for my problem regarding the use of jQuery to get some handle on it - [Replacing the Office 365 logo and link in Sharepoint Online Suite Bar](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/108695/replacing-the-office-365-logo-and-link-in-sharepoint-online-suite-bar)

2) Also if you want to read up about the possibilities of adding those links to the Personal Sites read the answer in this question - [Making global CSS changes in SPO 2013 MySite](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/111847/making-global-css-changes-in-spo-2013-mysite)

3) General instructions on how you can add jQuery in SPO - http://sp365.co.uk/2011/07/adding-jquery-to-sharepoint/

4) This site contains instructions on how to add links to the Suite Bar so it might give you a clue about how to apply that same kind of logic on how to add links on MySite the way you want to - http://blogs.c5insight.com/Home/entryid/440/Add-custom-links-to-the-SharePoint-2013-Suite-Bar-with-jQuery

I hope I have understood you correctly and I also hope that you can get something out of my answer! :)