# How to customize the User Profile Page(About me Page) in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-server, css, branding, mysites, userprofiles

I showed the user profile picture without using My sites,By clicking the user profile picture its redirect to my site host for edit profile page. I need to Customize that Page Layout and Look Feel for about me page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the layouts or master page for the mystite using SharePoint designer or if you want to maintain the changes on Source Control, you can copy the existing page, edit it in any text editor then upload it again to the master page gallery

Comment: How add a Custom Navigation in my sites? @HaithamShaddad

Comment: Check the answer for this questions http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/111478/changing-left-navigation-in-mysite-my-content-for-all-users