# How to make Sharepoint MySite Quick Navigation links available to the others

Tags: development, my-site, hyperlink, quick-launch, mysite

I have a SharePoint Solution written in C#.
This solution has an event receiver. When feature is activated this event receiver adds a link to Left Navigation menu.

When the feature is activated on a personal site (MySite) it looks like this
[image: How owner sees a link]

But other users do not see this link

[image: How others sees a link]

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
        SPWeb web = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb;

        if (web != null)
        {

            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

            SPList library = web.GetList(web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/Lists/" + "MyList");
            if (library != null)
            {
                SPListItem folder = library.Items.Add("", SPFileSystemObjectType.Folder, "FolderName");
                folder.Update();
                string title = "LinkForFolder";
                SPNavigationNodeCollection quickLaunch = web.Navigation.QuickLaunch;
                SPNavigationNode prgSum = new SPNavigationNode(title, library.DefaultViewUrl);
                SPNavigationNode previosLibraryNode = web.Navigation.GetNodeByUrl(library.DefaultViewUrl);
                if (previosLibraryNode != null)
                {
                    quickLaunch.Delete(previosLibraryNode);
                }

                SPNavigationNode previosNode = web.Navigation.GetNodeByUrl(web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/person.aspx");
                if (previosNode != null)
                {
                    quickLaunch.Add(prgSum, previosNode);
                }
                else
                {
                    quickLaunch.AddAsLast(prgSum);
                }

            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Event Receiver feature failed to get current context.");
        }
    }
```

And my question is - How to make a link visible to all?

Comment: Please share your code that adds the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the best way to do this would be to update the mysites master page.

Take a look at the following examples.

[Changing Left navigation in MySite (my content) for all users](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/111478/changing-left-navigation-in-mysite-my-content-for-all-users)
[Deep Dive into the Confusing SharePoint 2013 MySite Quick Launch Left Nav](http://www.lifeonplanetgroove.com/deep-dive-confusing-sharepoint-2013-mysite-quick-launch-left-nav/)

Comment: Thank you! But I thought that this can be done using a c#

Comment: Maybe you can. I just don't see the benefit of doing it that way. You're making it unnecessarily difficult.